# Continuous Delivery with VSTS and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I'm trying to get continuous delivery going with Jenkins (building, deploying) and VSTS (source control).  This is the desired workflow:

1. a developer branches off master, makes changes, creates a pull request
2. another developer reviews the PR and eventually merges it into master
3. some system (Jenkins or VSTS) detects that a PR was merged into master and...

   1. increments a version number stored in a file within the repo
   2. commits the version change back to master
   3. builds
   4. deploys

I was using Service Hooks within VSTS to detect the merge to master and execute a Jenkins task.  VSTS has 3 hooks I can use:

1. Build completed
2. Code pushed
3. Pull request merge commit created

I was under the impression that the third option would only occur when a PR was merged, but that's not the case.  Any additional commits to the branch, while it's associated with the PR triggers the hook.  This causes a bunch of unnecessary deployments.

I figured I could make Jenkins detect changes within VSTS.  There's a "Poll SCM" option, which takes a cron-like schedule.  The utterly confusing thing is, it doesn't appear that I can configure what exactly will be polled every X minutes (which repo, which branch).

What are my options here to trigger Jenkins tasks only when a PR is merged to master?  I would use the VSTS "Code pushed" Service Hook, but it goes into an infinite loop because Jenkins pushes to master when it increments the version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Create a new build definition for master
2. Select Triggers and enable Continuous Integration
3. Set the Branch Filters and Path filters (exclude the version number file that need to be changed)
4. Add task to modify version number file (e.g. PowerShell)
5. Add Command Line task (Tool: git; Arguments: config --global user.email “test@example.com”; Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory))
6. Add Command Line task (Tool: git; Arguments: config --global user.name "Your Name"; Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory))
7. Add Command Line task (Tool: git; Arguments: add [the modified file]; Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory))
8. Add Command Line task (Tool: git; Arguments: commit -m “update version”; Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory))
9. Add Command Line task (Tool:git; Arguments: push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName) ”; Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory))
10. Add [Jenkins Queue Job task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/jenkins-queue-job) to trigger Jenkins job

Comment: Interesting, so use VSTS' build services to trigger a Jenkins task?

Comment: Looking good, thanks for the suggestion!  It wasn't quite as straight forward as you said -- there were a lot of steps necessary to get it going (permissions for the build user to make commits, allowing scripts to access the oauth token, enabling the build to use git), but you pointed me in the right direction!